# mkdir(): Permission denied in XAMPP in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, mkdir

I tried to execute this code to create a folder inside userdata/profile_pics :

```
$chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   mkdir("userdata/user_photos/$rand_dir_name");
```

but it gives the following error :

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/findfriends/account_settings.php on line 88
```

How to make that code work ?

Comment: Set the correct permissions for the `user_photos/` directory and make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: change file permissions of `userdata` directory using your FTP to 775. if it still doesn't work 777. Just make sure webserver has write access to the folder. Don't forget to recurse to subdirectories, or just do it specifically to `userdata/user_photos/`.

Comment: How to set the correct permissions?
I am beginner. Please tell in an elaborate way

Comment: Like in this video for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zi0dl0MbkWw

Answer (score -2):

You must set permsissions for user_photos with write privileges..https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions